# How do I use constants from a Perl module?

Tags: perl, module, export, constants

If I define a constant in a Perl module, how do I use that constant in my main program?  (Or how do I call that constant in the main program?)

Comment: Best to avoid the "constant" package. http://earino.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/use-constant-will-surprise-you-with-its-evil/ Alternatives here: http://neilb.org/reviews/constants.html

Comment: @null Just because one guy hates them clashing with Perl bareword behavior in hash initializers? Thanks, but no, thanks. Tons of core modules use it without problem. Encode,  Compress::Raw::Bzip2/Zlib, Data::Dumper, File::Spec, etc.

Answer (score 52):

Constants can be exported just like other package symbols. Using the standard [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/~ferreira/Exporter-5.63/lib/Exporter.pm) module, you can export constants from a package like this:

```
package Foo;
use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Exporter';

use constant CONST => 42;

our @EXPORT_OK = ('CONST');

1;
```

Then, in a client script (or other module)

```
use Foo 'CONST';
print CONST;
```

You can use the `%EXPORT_TAGS` hash (see the Exporter documentation) to define groups of constants that can be exported with a single import argument.

Update: Here's an example of how to use the `%EXPORT_TAGS` feature if you have multiple constants.

```
use constant LARRY => 42;
use constant CURLY => 43;
use constant MOE   => 44;

our @EXPORT_OK = ('LARRY', 'CURLY', 'MOE');
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( stooges => [ 'LARRY', 'CURLY', 'MOE' ] );
```

Then you can say

```
use Foo ':stooges';
print "$_\n" for LARRY, CURLY, MOE;
```

Comment: use Exporter 'import';  is better, but will require upgrading Exporter on perl's earlier than 5.8.3.

Comment: please explain why is using 'import' better?

Comment: Best to avoid the "constant" package. http://earino.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/use-constant-will-surprise-you-with-its-evil/ Alternatives here: http://neilb.org/reviews/constants.html

Comment: @nslntmnx `use constant` benchmarks pretty well, generally.  It's true that one should read the documentation for it.

Comment: See, you go blowing through an example too quickly and you mess things up -- Copy & Paste FTW!  I just spent 5 minutes trying to get `our %EXPORT_OK = ( word => [ 'CONST1', 'CONST2' ] );` to work. :)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work if I write use constant ( LARRY => 42,
CURLY => 43, MOE   => 44 ); Why?

Answer (score 27):

Constants are just subs with empty prototype, so they can be exported like any other sub.

```
# file Foo.pm
package Foo;
use constant BAR => 123;
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(BAR);


# file main.pl:
use Foo qw(BAR);
print BAR;
```

Answer (score 22):

To expand on the earlier answers, since constants are really just subs, you can *also* call them directly:

```
use Foo;
print Foo::BAR;
```

Comment: Don't refer to answers as being above, because if your answer gets voted up enough, it may end up above them.

Answer (score 17):

You might want to consider using [Readonly](http://search.cpan.org/~roode/Readonly-1.03/Readonly.pm) instead of constant.

Comment: You can't do this with it: print "constant is $constant"; or this: print $hash{constant};

Comment: Since 'use constant' creates a subroutine, there are unexpected issues => no string interpolation, difficulty in using as a hash key.  See the docs for Readonly [ https://metacpan.org/module/Readonly#COMPARISON-WITH-use-constant ] .  Readonly use the perl internals to directly mark a variable as read-only.  Readonly is slow (unless using Readonly::XS) and unmaintained.  See also Data::Lock and Const::Fast for different implementations.

Comment: Actually you can interpolate constant in a string. Just use the same syntax you would use with any other function:
`use constant COLOR => 'red';
print "The color is @{[COLOR]}!";`

Answer (score 8):

```
package Foo;
use Readonly;
Readonly my  $C1 => 'const1';
Readonly our $C2 => 'const2';
sub get_c1 { return $C1 }
1;

perl -MFoo -e 'print "$_\n" for Foo->get_c1, $Foo::C2'
```

Answer (score 7):

To add to the bag of tricks, since a constant is just a subroutine you can even call it as a class method.

```
package Foo;
use constant PI => 3.14;

print Foo->PI;
```

If you have lots of constants it's a nice way to get at the occasional one without having to export them all.  However, unlike `Foo::PI` or exporting `PI`, Perl will not compile out `Foo->PI` so you incur the cost of a method call (which probably doesn't matter).