# How can I define constants in a separate file in Perl?

Tags: perl, constants

I have a bunch of Perl files which take in some filename constants. I would like to define these in a separate file - something like a header file in C. What's the best/most standard way of doing this in Perl?

Comment: Very close duplicate to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193020/how-do-i-use-constants-from-a-perl-module

Comment: @draegtun Actually it looks to complete duplicate - Q/A over there too explains defining constants in separate module, then exporting them and using them elsewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use constants from a Perl module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193020/how-do-i-use-constants-from-a-perl-module)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no equivalent to C header files in Perl. To declare and define global constants, you can use the [define](https://metacpan.org/pod/define) pragma. I have no experience with this module although the interface seems sensible.

On the other hand, you can write a module where you define constants and import them into your module using `use`. For example:

```
package MyConstants;

use strict; use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );
use Const::Fast;

our @EXPORT = qw();
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( $X $Y );

const our $X => 'this is X';
const our $Y => 'this is Y';

__PACKAGE__;
__END__
```

You can then use this module as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use MyConstants qw( $X );

print "$X\n";
print "$MyConstants::Y\n";
```

If you are OK with using fully qualified variable names (e.g. `$MyConstants::Y`), you do not need `Exporter` at all.

Also, make sure variables you export are not modifiable elsewhere (see the caution in [`Exporter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter) docs).

Of course, you could also define constants using [constant.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/constant). It may be faster to use such constants, but they are awkward if you need to interpolate them in a string.

Comment: Readonly::Scalar is pretty fast as well if you have Readonly::XS installed.  Hashes and Arrays are still slower though.

Comment: Note that the exporter docs ( http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html ) recommend that you do NOT export variables, even though it lets you.

Comment: @Robert P, IMO exporting a variable on request is reasonable, exporting one (or more!) by default is best avoided.  If in the example above, I was expecting to use $X many, many times and wanted to avoid the needless repetition of typing `$MyConstants::X` everywhere, it would be a huge benefit.  Another case for imported variables is that if I accidentally tried to use `$MyConstants::x`, no `strict` generated error message would alert me to my error, whereas, if I import `$X` and try to use `$x`, strict saves the day by catching the error.

Comment: I'll buy that.  I generally use the `use constant` form, and export those.  If I were using the Readonly package, that would probably make logical sense.

Comment: @Robert P: The variables that are exported in this case are not modifiable (and my answer links to the warning in the docs about exporting variables).

Answer (score 7):

We usually do this with a module name Constants. Something like:

```
package MyPackage::Constants;

our $DIR = "/home/chriss";
our $MAX_FILES = 5;

1;
```

Then, to use it:

```
package MyPackage;
use MyPackage::Constants;

open(my $fh, ">", $MyPackage::Constants::DIR . "/file");
```

If you didn't want to reference the package all the time, you could use Exporter and bring in all the symbols you want.

Comment: Why not define the MyPackage constants in the MyPackage module itself, rather than making a new namespace? And if you refer to the constant as namespace::DIR, you lose the advantage of inheritance, i.e. MyPackage::Child::Constants can't inherit from MyPackage::Constants and override the value of DIR. namespace->DIR is much better.

Comment: This is a simplistic example for illustrative purposes. That said, not everything is OO :)

Comment: That looks like configuration, not constants.

Comment: Also, why declare these as variables rather than constants? See http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html as Sinan's post describes.

Comment: brian d foy's right, this is configuration. However, in the work I do there are very few "constant" constants (no math stuff, etc.), so most of what I do is configuration.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like configuration settings, which would be better put in a config file that you parse with one of the various CPAN modules, for instance [Config::Any](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-Any).

Configuration is data, which IMO shouldn't be in your code.

Answer (score -2):

One way would be to write them as a perl module, that you can subsequently include with "require" or "use". You'd write your file like this -- give it a .pm extension (e.g., myFabulousPackage.pm)

```
package myFabulousPackage;

$someSetting=45;
$otherSetting='Fish';

1;
```

Then in your perl script, this would include the file and then reference $otherSetting:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use myFabulousPackage;

print $myFabulousPackage::otherSetting;
```

This is just a very simple view of what you can do with a package/module, but for what you need, this might be the simplest way to implement it. Similarly, you can put sub's in the package as well, and reference them in a similar way.

Comment: This won't work.  Variables declared with my (lexical variables) are not accessible via `$PackageName::varname`.  This syntax only accesses variables in the symbol table.  The best way to put variables in the symbol table is to use `our` to declare them.

Comment: That won't actually work. The `my` declaration of the variables makes them lexically scoped, and thus only visible to code in the `.pm` file. You want them to be declared with `our` instead. Also, it's a good idea to always terminate module files with `1;` because if the last statement somehow evaluates to a false value, the module won't load.

Comment: Yep -- you're right about the 'my' ... that's me writing perl on auto-pilot, and not double checking my examples. Edit'd.

Comment: Chris J: you can use "our" instead of "my"

Comment: Please use "use strict; use warnings;", which will prevent you from implicitly declaring new variables. You should always use either "our" or "my", which these pragmas will enforce.