# perl constant definition in a dedicated package

Tags: perl, constants, package, declaration, shared

I would like to set up a dedicated package for all common declarations to main perl program and other packages as well, without repeating these declarations in every headers. I get it wrong for sure but could not figure out the rationals behind that :

Let's assume :
- I have setup my common data within the package **my_common_declarations.pm**.
- I want to use these data within another package,  **my_perl_utils.pm** for example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
package my_perl_utils;
use parent qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(f1 f2);
use my_common_declarations qw(debugme);
my %setup = &debugme;
my $DEBUGME = $setup{setup}{debugme};

# This generates this error : "Use of uninitialized value"
use constant true => $setup{setup}{'true'};
print "=" x25, "\nDEBUG true :\nimport = " . $setup{setup}{'true'} . "\nconstant = " , true , "\n", "=" x25, "\n"; 

sub f1{
# some rationals using the true or false constants
}

sub f2{
}

1;
```

I can't succeed in getting the 'true' constant declared without errors.

Shall I import the common declarations package only once in the main program and declare the constant accordingly in there, or redeclare it within each package where I need this constant ?

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are running into is the interaction between runtime and compile time in your script.  Any `use` declaration has an implicit `BEGIN {...}` block around it, which means that it takes place at compile time.  Your assignment to `%setup` happens at runtime, after the constant has been declared.  The fix for this is to declare the variable, and then perform the assignment to it in a `BEGIN` block.  That way, the variable will be defined by the time `use constant ...` is called:

```
use my_common_declarations 'debugme';

my (%setup, $DEBUGME);  # declare variables with file scope

BEGIN {
    %setup   = debugme;                # assign to variables at compile time
    $DEBUGME = $setup{setup}{debugme};
}

use constant true => $setup{setup}{true}; # %setup is defined now
```

Alternatively, since you are exporting a function that returns a hash, why not have it return a hash reference, then you could write your code as:

```
use my_common_declarations 'debugme';

use constant true => debugme->{setup}{true};
```

In that case, since `debugme` is imported by the first `use` statement at compile time, it is available in the `use constant ...` line.

But since you are declaring a package for common declarations, why not just move the definition of your constants into that package, and then add things like `true` to the export list for that package?

Comment: thx I'll look carefully to your comments and try to implement.

Comment: But he's also using an underscore in the package name, which means it's reserved for local use (just like he's doing).  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658955/how-do-i-choose-a-package-name-for-a-custom-perl-module-that-does-not-collide) for details.

Comment: @cjm => Thanks for pointing that out, I have removed that portion of my answer.

Comment: I did move the definition of the constants into the package as adviced, much better, many thx. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193020/how-do-i-use-constants-from-a-perl-module) helped.